# Spring taglib in uiBinder xml-file

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, gwt, uibinder, taglib

How can I put my taglib prefix correctly in my name.ui.xml file, is it even possible ?

In an html/jsp file it normally would work with

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
```

But thats not the case with uiBinder xml files. Is there a way or an alternative ? I'm trying to ensure multilingualism in my application. Thx for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do understand that JSP is processed by your server, and UiBinder is processed by the GWT compiler to produce JS for the browser (client), right?

If you want to internationalize your GWT application, there are tools for that: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/doc/latest/DevGuideI18n.html

Comment: Thx for the link, I think I need to read up about this topic. Are there some pointers you can give me to ensure multilingualism in my application. I'm kinda new to this topic.